# Android Phone communicates with two micro-controllers using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, microcontroller, android-bluetooth

I am trying to connect my smartphone to two microcontrollers with RN42 bluetooth module.

I am able to communicate with both of them individually, but when I open start the connection with the second one, the first one is closed.
I used the Multi Bluetooth Chat example as starting point. But I really don't if that example is more focus on connecting several slaves to one master instead of connecting one master to several slaves (that is my case).

I don't know if I should give you my project, it is to many lines and actually is almost exactly the same than BluetoothChatMulti project. Anyway if some you need it just ask for it.

I have been looking for a solution in forums and on Internet but I didn't find the solution to my project. Hope any of you have been already by this problem and can help me.

Best Regards!

Comment: Hi, generally Bluetooth RFcomm servers are meant to be connected to a single client. As per the Android Developers site [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#TheBasics), : **Unlike TCP/IP, RFCOMM only allows one connected client per channel at a time** .

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that the smartphone will connect to two devices, not waiting for incoming connections.
I know that Android can manage two devices (for example an bluetooth headphones and bluetooth heart monitor), so it should be possible to do it with other devices by developing my own application. But as I said, once I start my second connection, the first one is closed.

Comment: Android can definitely manage two devices at a time. However, in case of your multichat app which uses serial port profile, only one device client can connect to server, which is a limitation in Android. If you could tell a bit about your project, a better focused solution can be provided to you.